# Retrofit 2 авторизация методом post

Tags: android, retrofit2

Здравствуйте!

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с авторизацией Retrofit 2, на сайте методом POST в качестве параметров передаются login и password. 
В качестве ответа я должен получить

```
{
"data": {
    "token": "BxSGg2QK00-2PeKfG1Cw2RuBCleWjJ09"
},
"error": null,
"system": {
    "time": 0.405633
}}
```

Если не сложно опишите пожалуйста подробнее.

---

Что я делаю не так??? Добавил в activity реализацию retrofit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://mysite.ru/v1/authorize/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
    loginRequest.login = "admin";
    loginRequest.password = "admin";

    Call<LoginResponse> call = api.login(loginRequest);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
            if (loginResponse != null) {
                Log.d("authLog", loginResponse.data.token);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("authLog", t.getMessage());

        }
    });
}}
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

```
04-19 08:37:24.475 1892-1892/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.ru.authorizatioapp, PID: 1892
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at example.ru.authorizatioapp.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:43)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Кто нибудь сможет мне помочь, как получить результат???

Answer (score 4):

Метод авторизации:

```
@POST("user/login")
Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

POJO с использованием аннотаций из Gson будут выглядеть так.

Запрос:

```
public class LoginRequest {

   public LoginRequest(String login, String password) {
      this.login = login;
      this.password = password;
   }

   @SerializedName("login")
   String login;

   @SerializedName("password")
   String password;

}
```

Ответ:

```
public class LoginResponse {

   @Nullable
   @SerializedName("data")
   public Data data;

   public class Data {

      @Nullable
      @SerializedName("token")
      public String token;

   }

   @Nullable
   @SerializedName("error")
   public String error;

   @Nullable
   @SerializedName("system")
   public System system;

   public class System {

      @Nullable
      @SerializedName("time")
      public double time;

   }

}
```

---

***UPD.*** Так же советую ознакомиться с [официальной документацией](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность, а как вызвать нужные методы для получения самого token'а? Дело в том что у меня именно с этим большая проблема, не могу уловить суть как обрабатывает Retrofit обрабатывает указанные поля и как получить результат JSON'а

Comment: @dev.android, у вашего метода авторизации вызываете `enqueue`, в `onResponse` вашего колбека ловите успешный ответ. `Token` в классе `LoginResponse` - обычное поле, причём `public`. Так что обращаетесь напрямую - `loginResponse.data.token`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: @dev.android, ещё дополнил ответ ссылкой на документацию. Там всё расписано понятно, а примеры покрывают практически все тривиальные задачи

Comment: Читал я документацию. Не совсем понял, поэтому и хотел что бы мне здесь помогли в моем примере((